# c++ winldap not returning all entries. Stopping at 4000

Tags: c++, c++11, ldap

I am writing a basic ldap query in c++ that will need to return our servers/workstations. I found this example off of Microsofts site and have changed it up a little to fit what I need.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367016(v=vs.85).aspx

I am able to bind to our servers and run queries with no issue and dump it into a log file, but I am unable to return more than 4000 objects. Our domain is very large with subdomains, and we will need to query more than 4000. I am able to run a query against the same Domain Controller with powershell and that returns all the objects. Query I am running for testing purposes is: "(objectCategory=computer)"I would like to keep it in c++ since I will be integrating it with an already existing program.

According to: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366971(v=vs.85).aspx
I should be able to set the sizelimit to 0 and all entries should be returned (Unless my understanding on what they mean by entries is wrong). However, changing from ldap_search_s() to ldap_search_ext_s and setting a flag for LDAP_NO_LIMIT or 0 made no difference on the amount of entries returned. As of now I have been stuck trying to figure out why I can't return all entries with what I have.

Here is what I got for code.

```
`//New Class//
Search *s = new Search;
ULONG numReturned = 0; //No Limit
char *LdapServer = "Domain.com";
//Init ssl//
LDAP *ldap = ldap_sslinitA(LdapServer, LDAP_SSL_PORT, 1);
unsigned long version = LDAP_VERSION3;
ldap_set_option(ldap, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, (void*)&version);
ldap_set_option(ldap, LDAP_OPT_SIZELIMIT, (void*)&numReturned);

//Define what attributes to return//
PCHAR pMyAttributes[2];
pMyAttributes[0] = "distinguishedName";
pMyAttributes[1] = NULL;

//Message return handle//
LDAPMessage *pMsg = NULL;
unsigned long connectSuccess = ldap_connect(ldap, NULL);
if (connectSuccess == LDAP_SUCCESS) {
    std::cout << "Connection to ldap successful\n";
    ldap_simple_bind(ldap, s->user, s->pw);
    std::string beginSearch = "";
std::cout << "Enter your custom query:\n";
        std::getline(std::cin, beginSearch);
        ldap_search_ext_s(ldap, "dc=Domain,dc=com", LDAP_SCOPE_SUBTREE, 
(PSTR)beginSearch.c_str(), pMyAttributes, NULL, NULL, NULL,NULL, 
LDAP_NO_LIMIT, &pMsg);
        ULONG numberOfEntries;
        numberOfEntries = ldap_count_entries(ldap, pMsg);
        if (numberOfEntries == NULL) {
            std::cout << "Ldap entries returned fail with 0x" << 
connectSuccess << "\n";
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "Entries returned: " << numberOfEntries;
            LDAPMessage *pEntry = NULL;
            PCHAR pEntryDN = NULL;
            ULONG iCnt = 0;
            char* sMsg;
            BerElement *pBer = NULL;
            PCHAR pAttribute = NULL;
            PCHAR *ppValue = NULL;
            ULONG iValue = 0;

            //Loop through the entries//
            for (iCnt = 0; iCnt < numberOfEntries; iCnt++) {
                //Get the first/next entry//
                if (!iCnt)
                    pEntry = ldap_first_entry(ldap, pMsg);
                else
                    pEntry = ldap_next_entry(ldap, pEntry);
                //Output status message//
                sMsg = (!iCnt ? "ldap_first_entry" : "ldap_next_entry");
                if (pEntry == NULL) {
                    std::cout << "failed with 0x" << sMsg << 
LdapGetLastError();
                    ldap_unbind_s(ldap);
                    ldap_msgfree(pMsg);
                    return -1;
                }
                else
                    std::cout << "Succeeded\n" << sMsg;
                std::cout << "Entry Number: " << iCnt;
                pAttribute = ldap_first_attribute(ldap, pEntry, &pBer); 
//Session Handle, Current Entry, [out] Current BerElement


//Begin outputting the attribute names for the current object and ouput 
values//
                while (pAttribute != NULL) {
                    std::cout << "ATTR: " << pAttribute;
                    Log(pAttribute);

                    //get string values
                    ppValue = ldap_get_values(ldap, pEntry, pAttribute); 
//Session handle, current entry, current attribute
                    if (ppValue == NULL)
                        std::cout << "\nNo Attribute value returned!\n";
                    else {
                        iValue = ldap_count_values(ppValue);
                        if (!iValue)
                            std::cout << "BAD VALUE LIST!\n";
                        else {
                            //Output the first attribute//
                            std::cout << ": " << *ppValue;
                            Log(*ppValue);
                            //If there are more, continuing outputting//
                            ULONG z;
                            for (z = 1; z < iValue; z++) {
                                std::cout << ", " << ppValue[z];
                                Log(ppValue[z]);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (ppValue != NULL)
                        ldap_value_free(ppValue);
                    ppValue = NULL;
                    ldap_memfree(pAttribute);
                    pAttribute = ldap_next_attribute(ldap, pEntry, pBer);
                    std::cout << "\n";
                }
                if (pBer != NULL)
                    ber_free(pBer, 0);
                pBer = NULL;
            }
            ldap_unbind(ldap);
            ldap_msgfree(pMsg);
            ldap_value_free(ppValue);
        }
    }
}
`
```

I appreciate any help or pointers. Sorry if my code is hard to read.

Comment: Do you have the same problem if you remove `ldap_count_entries()` altogether and change that first `for` loop into a `while` loop that breaks when `ldap_(first|next)_entry()` returns NULL? No reason to count the entries before enumerating them.  Same with enumerating an entry's attribute values, for that matter. Try changing that `for` loop into a `while` loop, too.  You are already using a `while` loop to enumerate an entry's attributes, so you may as well use `while` loops for everything.

Comment: I removed the 'for (iCnt = 0; iCnt < numberOfEntries; iCnt++) ' and replaced it with a while loop that breaks when the ldap_next_entry() returns NULL. Also removed the 'ldap_count_entries()' as well. However, my query still stops when it hits the 4000 mark.

Comment: I also open'd up ADSI and check the Default Query Policy and it looks like the MaxPageSize is set to 1000 and the MaxRestulSetSize is set to 262144. 
I am still not sure why Powershell returns 14000+ entries but I only get 4000.  

I also did add this before the ldap search call. 
'lcontrol = NULL'
'ldap_create_page_control(ldap, 10240, NULL, 'T', &lcontrol) '

I based my code off of: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_i5_54/apis/ldap_create_page_control.htm

Results still topped out at 4000

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that the AD you're requesting has also a sizelimit set on the server.

The one you are configuring is client side but can't overwrite the server one.

If your administrator does not want to change the server sizelimit, you will have to request using `paged results` controls

I don't know how to implement this in C++ though

Comment: See [`ldap_search_init_page()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366973.aspx) and [`ldap_get_next_page()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366591.aspx)/[`ldap_get_next_page_s()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366592.aspx)

Comment: I will give those functions a shot and get back to you. Thank you!

Comment: Looks like when I try going the paged results search functions I get LDAP error 12: SB_LDAP_RESULT_UNAVALIABLE_CRITICAL_EXTENSION. Seems our ldap servers may not server side page sorting...
I also went and got the ldap calls made through the ADSI api, but that seems to only return the 1000 limit which matches the max page size limit on our servers.  Problem with that way, when I reach the end of the row at 1000, the search just stops and hangs.  Doesn't seem to want to get the next row for some reason.  Either way, if I get either working, I will update some more.

Comment: Just updating on this issue. As of now, I haven't found a way past the 4000 limit.  For now I am breaking down my single call into multiple calls instead to get around it.

Comment: do you have a sample with ldap_search_init_page() ?